# Show old and new row data on same row

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

How would I go about the following:

```
AgreementID
Name
DOB
Address
PhoneNo
Email
RowNumber (I've added this on myself using Row_NUMBER with name and dob)
```

So imagine Joe Bloggs has 2 agreements and on the 2nd agreement, some of his contact details have changed.  So the visual representation I require via TSQL is:

```
AgreementID  Name  DOB  CurrentAddress, CurrentEmail, CurrentPhone,   
                        OldAddress    , OldEmail    , OldPhone
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add some sample data?

Comment: Seemingly you are looking for the 'output' clause of an update https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx.

Comment: First make a table with the columns you need to see, like the ones you have mentioned. Then, in an update trigger, join the inserted and deleted tables on pk and populate the relevant columns depending on which of the three fields (address, email, phone) have changed. I can help with you the trigger if you get stuck.

There is no other place where you can get access to old and new data together without storing them specifically in temp tables.

Comment: And what if Joe Bloggs had 5 agreements.  Why not just sort on Name, AgreementID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display different entries of data from the same column, perhaps try a Self-join to another instance of the the same table.

The client 'Joe Bloggs' should have a unique identifier in a 'Clients' table.  How do you know he has two agreements and not just his son that lives in the same location with the same name?  you could create a composite key from Name + DOB.

What if someone has 50 agreements with you? which ones do you want to display.  You can compare the two most recent agreements with a MAX(agreementID) grouped by your clientID (maybe a hashed composite key from name + dob).  Then use a window function ordered by agreementID and compare it to the second most-recent.

Finding Min(AgreementID) and Max(AgreementID) grouped by Name+DOB would get you the first and current information for your client.

Try something like this for Min/Max agreementID per client:

```
ALTER [TABLE]
ADD ClientID TEXT(50)

UPDATE [Table]
SET ClientID = (Name + CAST(DOB AS NVARCHAR(30)))

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT MIN(AgreementID) AS 'minID', MAX(AgreementID) AS 'maxID', ClientID FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY ClientID
)
SELECT ClientID, T1.DOB,  T2.Address AS 'CurrentAddress', T2.Email AS 'CurrentEmail', T2.PhoneNo AS 'CurrentPhone',  T1.Address AS 'OldAddress', T1.Email AS 'OldEmail', T1.PhoneNo AS 'OldPhone'
FROM cte
    JOIN [Table] T1 ON cte.ClientID = T1.ClientID
    AND T1.AgreementID = cte.minID
    JOIN [Table] T2 ON cte.ClientID = T2.ClientID
    AND T2.AgreementID = cte.maxID
```

You can then restrict your results even further to only display results where information has changed by checking for differences between T1 and T2 on the fields you allow updates to.

Comment: Many Thanks Emuevil.  There is a requirement to show all agreements as you stated e.g. 20.  Row 1 Would be Agr1 and Null, 2 = Agr2 and Agr1, 3 = Arg3 and Agr2, 4 = Agr4 and Agr3

Comment: You'll want to create a Common Table Expression that uses the `LAG` window function on the `MAX(agreementID)` grouped by `ClientID` from a result set of your Agreements table grouped by `ClientID`.  Partition by your `ROW_NUMBER()` Ordered by `AgreementID`.  This way, you can offset the address/email/phone info to be the penultimate entry for each Client.  Use these links to assist you: 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx